# How can I change random string inside link?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm trying to delete some random value string from link. But I couldn't do that. How can I do it properly?

There is my code:

```
self.baslikLinki.replacingOccurrences(of: "applewebdata://[0-9A-Z-]*/?", with: "category/user/", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

The link looks like:

```
applewebdata://DA4343F3-A092-4BF1-B76F-7FC7F128C7D9/?q=se%c3%a7im+yasaklar%c4%b1
```

Comment: Add the code what have tried also what is there in "baslikLinki"

Comment: And what part is this random string to replace, is it always the part between  "applewebdata://" and the following "/"?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson After the applewebdata:// till ?q= string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse the URL and replace the host and path with your desired string!

```
let link = "applewebdata://DA4343F3-A092-4BF1-B76F-7FC7F128C7D9/?q=se%c3%a7im+yasaklar%c4%b1"
var url = URLComponents(string: link)!
url.host = "category"
url.path = "/user/"
print("\(url)") // applewebdata://category/user/?q=se%c3%a7im+yasaklar%c4%b1
```

Answer (score -2):

For simple replacement:

```
 let originalString= "xyzABC"
 let replaced = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "ABC", with: "whatever")
```

For regex:

```
var originalString = "!hi !!"
let pattern = "!h%"
originalString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: You need to update your answer with a pattern that is relevant for for answering the question, otherwise this answer isn't very useful